# How do you allow de-opped players to use ServerSigns in MC 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

So, my group and I are setting up an initial spawn room for a server we are creating. The room is like an introduction area, with important information. After the player has read all the signs and stuff, there are two signs (that will have the same commands) that basically do these few things:

a. Teleport the player from the initial spawn to Hub.

b. Transfer the player from the Group Manager group "Default" to "Marine" (basically the base rank for all players)

The main reason the player changes groups is because Marine will have different stats than the Default players. (ie. prefixes, spawn, sign perms, etc.)

However, the problem is, we can't make it so that de-opped players in the Default group can use ServerSigns. I am in the Developers group with NO permissions at all, but I can still use signs even when de-opped.

I know there is the serversigns.use.* thing, but I have no idea where to input this. We have tried doing /mangaddp Default serversigns.use.* but this does not work. Help is appreciated! *Note that I don't really understand the GroupManager plugin too well, so please be patient with me.* :)

Comment: I never used group manger I always used pex just cuz I liked it a lot better... But basicly you just need to add it in to their group manger group

Comment: I could talk to the Owner about pex. Is it Bukkit compatible? If so, could you add a link?

Comment: I believe so, since I ran it on spigot witch is just a modified version of bukkit, but here is the link https://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/

Comment: Thanks! I will run this by the owner, and test out some commands. I'll get back to this thread if I continue to have trouble.

Comment: To add it it would be /pex group marine add serversigns.use.* , but best of luck let me know how it goes

Comment: So we can't use pex commands all too well because we aren't promoted, and we can't promote ourselves because we don't have enough permissions. Then, when we do it from console, we're aren't "in the ladder"?

Comment: You need to op your self from the main console first, since pex overrides everything

Comment: Well it doesn't matter anymore, the owner doesn't want to use it. He's being very impatient :/

Comment: Would you be able to send me the permission.yml file from the group manger folder and I can see if I can figure it out real fast, you can send it via Skype if you want @ Jaconah98

Comment: Sure, just sent a request.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, when doing the `/svs add` put `/svs add *[command]` and not `/svs add /[command]`. It will allow all players to use the ServerSign.

To make a special sign do `/svs setperm [perm]` and only players with the `-serversigns.use.perm` can use it. (the perm is what you typed in the `setperm` command)

The first command requires no perms else than `serversigns.use` and it will even execute commands like `/give` or `/promote`.

Oh, and if you want to make a sign that promotes a user (or does something to the user) who clicked on the sign you do

```
/svs add *promote [player]
```

You write the `[player]` thing with brackets, instead of the username. It puts the clicking player's name as it.